# Fatal error: Call to undefined function base_url() in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, base-url

Hello I am new to CodeIgniter and PHP, I am trying to setup it for the firs time, but it give the following error.

i used wammp and i have folder name ' taxiapp ' inside ' www '
please help me of this :

below my dashboard.php and autoloaded.php and config.php

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function base_url() in C:\wamp64\www\TaxiApp\application\views\dashboard.php on line 17 ( ! ) Error: Call to undefined function base_url() in C:\wamp64\www\TaxiApp\application\views\dashboard.php on line 17 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0005405632{main}( )...\dashboard.php:0

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
ini_set('display_startup_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="google-translate-customization" content="e6d13f48b4352bb5- 
f08d3373b31c17a6-g7407ad622769509b-12"></meta>

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

<title>Dashboard - 24/7 Taxi</title>

<!-- bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();? 
>application/views/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
<!-- RTL support - for demo only -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>application/views/js/demo-rtl.js"> 
</script>
<!-- 
If you need RTL support just include here RTL CSS file <link 
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/libs/bootstrap-rtl.min.css" />
And add "rtl" class to <body> element - e.g. <body class="rtl"> 
-->'
```

autloader.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://172.20.10.3/TaxiApp/';
```

Comment: can you try this `$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/TaxiApp';`?

Comment: @M.Hemant where to put this command ? and what is the server_name ?

Comment: in config.php replace with your line and do print_r($config);die;

Comment: @M.Hemant the print command in the config.php or dashboard.php ?

Comment: in config, and compare it with your old static base_url

Comment: Notice : Undefined Index :172.20.10.3 ( My Server ) in config.php                              My Command is                                                                            
       $config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['172.20.10.3'].'/TaxiApp';

Comment: Did you change `SERVER_NAME` in mine string? I think the problem is in your folder structure

Comment: Yes Changed It .... What the folder structure must be ??

Comment: Error is Gone ... but Blank White page is appear without any errors or comments ?

Comment: from which change are you getting `Blank White page is appear without any errors or comments`? and why did you changed this `'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/TaxiApp'` to `'http://'.$_SERVER['172.20.10.3'].'/TaxiApp'`?

Answer (score -1):

Keep `css` and `js` folders along with `application` folder and change `href` and `src` values accordingly.

**TaxiApp**

-- application

-- css

-- js

Comment: how to put it along with application??

Comment: Cut both folders and paste them in the directory where `application` folder is.

Comment: Error is Gone ... but Blank White page is appear without any errors or comments ?

Comment: You might have changed the values of `href` and `src` accordingly. Now check `route.php` in `config` folder (inside `application` folder) for rest.